# How to create a fixed table header through pear html table with mysql database

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Currently I'm using php and pear_html table to create a html table.But i have try many ways to keep the table header to fixed while scrolling the table but end up the words all is duplicated together and fixed.

Here is the CSS style I use:

for fix table header:

```
 table.result th {
 position:fixed;
display:inline-block;
}
```

for set the scrollbar for tbody

```
table.result tbody{
 display:block;
 height:450px; 
 overflow:auto;
 }
```

[image: Image for Fixed Table]

Comment: Show your code in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i cant show a full code in jsfiddle because it use the php to show the database table .i'm using the javascript to call the php table

Comment: You can copy html structure in browser and insert to jsfiddle.
It is not necessary that this work